# Need single SQL Query to get result from 2 tables with common column

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
| social | country | reward_id |
|--------|---------|-----------|
| 1      | CA      | 1         |
| 2      | CA      | 1         |
| 3      | AU      | 1         |
| 4      | AU      | 2         |
| 5      | CA      | 1         |
```

Table 2

```
| visit | country | reward_id |
|--------|---------|-----------|
| 1      | CA      | 1         |
| 2      | IN      | 1         |
| 3      | AU      | 1         |
| 4      | IN      | 2         |
| 5      | CA      | 1         |
```

Output should be count of both tables like

```
| country| social | visit |
|--------|---------|-----------|
| CA      | 3      | 2         |
| AU     | 2      | 1         |
| IN      | 0      | 1         |
```

as we are fetching only for reward_id = 1

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select country, sum(social) as social, sum(visit) as visit
from ((select country, 1 as social, 0 as visit
       from social
       where reward_id = 1
      ) union all
      (select country, 0 as social, 1 as visit
       from visit
       where reward_id = 1
      )
     ) sv
group by country;
```